# Increasing PHP's memory_limit on Ubuntu 20 not working

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm running a php script via terminal and I get this error message `Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted`.

So i then added `ini_set("memory_limit", "4096M");` to the php file and that did not work.
Then i run `php --ini` to see which loaded cli file (/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini) is being used and after editing said file i found that there is no memory limit set in it `ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");`

I have no idea what's going on (not very linux savvy). Where is it drawing the conclusion that it only has 512M of available memory?

**Edit #1**: I also did a `phpinfo()` which said the `php.ini` file is at `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` so I edited that file as well, still getting the same result (restarted apache and initiated a new terminal window as well)

**Edit #2**: the script is run by `php mylocalphpfile.php -params`

Ubuntu 20, php 7.4

Comment: Edit php.ini , then restart httpd

Comment: @KenLee a) the OP stated that he has edited the file b) running a script on the terminal is not affected in any way by httpd

Comment: Please share more details. How do you run that script?

Comment: Would have to wonder what you are doing that requires so much memory! Probably something badly

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's a custom script for transpileing postgres dump into a mysql dump, and the dump file is 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found out that the forked script from Github has some references to other dependencies in which the memory_limit is being forced to be 512M.

Removed that line of code form the lib and now it's working.